Playwright JavaScript - Upload image
I spent hours trying to figure out how to solve the following.
I am automating a test case with Playwright - JavaScript where I have to upload an image but it gives me all kinds of errors, the last one I am trying to test is with the documentation uploaded in playwright.dev
Test:
const path = require('path');
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
test("s", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://www.transfernow.net/es');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Inicio' }).click();
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Inicio' }).first().setInputFiles(path.join(__dirname, 'images.png'));
 }); 

Error:
Error: locator.setInputFiles: Error: Node is not an HTMLInputElement
Call log:

waiting for getByRole('button', { name: 'Inicio' }).first()
locator resolved to …

How i can fix this?.

I meant I couldn't figure it out.

Eric- to fix this issue, you need to make sure that you are using the setInputFiles() method on an input element of type "file" that is visible and enabled.

Thanks Vishal!! Your comment was correct! I was able to solve it!!!

You are welcome Eric , glad I could help.

If its a file input and not a button then you dont need to click it. Just locate the input and use the .setInputFIles() funciton

As mentioned in the comment , please make sure that you are using the setInputFiles() method on an input element of type "file" that is visible and enabled.


As per the Error: Node is not an HTMLInputElement

Indicates that setInputFiles method is being called on a node that is not an HTML input element of type file. In order to fix this, you need to ensure that you are targeting the correct file input element on the webpage.
Refer the code below for reference :


import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
const path = require('path');

test("Upload image", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://www.transfernow.net/es');  // navigate to your site    
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Inicio' }).click(); // Click button    
    const fileInput = await page.$('input[type="file"]'); // Locate the file   
    if (fileInput) {      
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'images.png'); // Set the file to upload
        await fileInput.setInputFiles(filePath);
    } else {
        console.error('File input element not found');
    }
   // any other action you needs to do.. comes here
});



